# Where is Oracle home user being stored

Tags: oracle, installation

Oracle 12c has introduced Oracle home user in its installation process. I have searched and read some articles about Oracle home user. (Please see screenshot below)

My questions are:

1. If I use create new windows user, I typed username and password here, after the installation, I do not see a windows user is created in my windows system(control panel -> manage account). Do I need to create a windows user with the same name and password in order to use the database? Or I do not need to create anything, it is just a windows user hidden somewhere in my system. And what Did this create new windows user really do.
2. Oracle says use this create new windows user, the user will not have login privilege. What does this mean, it has no login privilege for windows? or for Oracle database.
3. First time I tried to install Oracle database, it was hanging at 88%. I uninstalled and deleted everything I know, then I started to install it again, this time if I use "Create new windows user", and use the same user name, it told me Specified User is already exists. As I said before, there is no such user in my windows.(control panel -> manage account). Now if I use a new one, it will work. Is there any way I can find where was the previous user stored? I checked the inventory.xml, its not in there.

[image: Oracle Home User Selection]

Comment: Did the things you already read include [this](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTQRF/oh_usr.htm#NTQRF672) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTDBI/install.htm#r9c1-t24)?

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank you for your link, I read the first one. I got something new from the second:

Create New Windows User
Provide the user name and password for the Windows Local User that you want Oracle Universal Installer to create. Confirm the password. The new user that is created is denied interactive logon privileges to the Windows computer. However, a Windows administrator can manage this account like any other Windows account.

But I still don't understand this. So it is a windows user which I can see in my windows account management? But I don't see it. Can you give me your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the user folders was in the windows user path, but for some reason these are not normal windows users, so it is not visible to the account management. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try to specify a domain name + username